# Integral of Absolute of a Function

Tags: integration

Suppose the function $f$ to be integrable on the closed interval $[a,b]$. Prove that the function $|f|$ is also integrable on that interval.

Comment: To what kind of integration theory are you referring?

Comment: $f=f^+-f^-$ is integrable, iff $f^+$ and $f^-$ are integrable where $f^+(x)=\max \{f(x),0\}$ and $f^-(x)=-\min\{f(x),0\}$

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment, so feel free to comment out.

You know $f$ is integrable in $(a,b)$. Then, you also know that $-f$ is integrable in $(a,b)$. Also, $f$ is integrable in every interval $(c,d)\subset (a,b)$.

Let $(c_i^+,d_i^+)\subset(a,b)$ all the intervals where $f$ is positive, and $(c_i^-,d_i^-)\subset(a,b)$ all the intervals where $f$ is negative. Then, $|f|$ is integrable because you can integrate $f$ in every interval where is positive, and then integrate $-f$ in every interval where $f$ is negative, so
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\int_a^b|f|\,dx&=&\sum_i\int_{c_i^+}^{d_i^+}(f)\,dx+\sum_i\int_{c_i^-}^{d_i^-}(-f)\,dx\\
&=&\sum_i\int_{c_i^+}^{d_i^+}(f)\,dx-\sum_i\int_{c_i^-}^{d_i^-}(f)\,dx
\end{array}$$

And every integral in both sums is defined, because is evaluated in a subset of $(a,b)$, where $f$ is integrable.